# JavaFX apply effect on a BackgroundImage

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

### Situation

I am using a BackgroundImage to set the background for a JavaFX Region, like this:

```java
region.setBackground(Background(BackgroundImage(Image(url)), BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize(100.0, 100.0, true, true, true, true))))
```

### Problem

I would like to darken the background somehow so that the white font stays readable.

### What I've tried

I have searched through Image, BackgroundImage and Background, but none have any way to add an effect.
I found that I can add an effect directly to the Region, but when I add the ColorAdjust, it darkens everything, not just the background.

I really don't care at which layer it is set, it could even be in CSS, I simply want to somehow darken the BackgroundImage.

Comment: You could put a `Region` in another parent (e.g. a `StackPane`) along with your other content. Put the background image on the `Region` and apply the affect to it.

Comment: Slaw's comment is sufficient to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply an `Effect` to a node it affects all of its children, if it has any. You also can't apply an `Effect` to a `Background` specifically as it provides no API to do so<sup>1</sup>. Instead, what you can do is have a separate `Region` to use for your background image and then place it and your other content in a common parent. You could then apply the `Effect` to this "background region" and only affect it, not any other nodes. A parent that would work well for this situation is a `StackPane` since it will stack your other content above the "background region"; it will also resize the region to fill up all available space (making it effectively a background image).

```
// Can also apply background through CSS or FXML. Same with the
// effect, though only DropShadow and InnerShadow can be set through
// CSS—any effect can be set though FXML.
Region backgroundRegion = new Region();
backgroundRegion.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(...)));
backgroundRegion.setEffect(new ColorAdjust(...));

Node otherContent = ...;

StackPane parent = new StackPane(backgroundRegion, otherContent);
// add "parent" to scene graph...
```

Note I'd use a `Region`, like above, rather than an `ImageView` as the former will keep the behavior of a background image; it's not that easy to imitate a background image with an `ImageView` (at least in my experience).

---

<sup>1. This applies to code, CSS, and FXML. Note that CSS and FXML are just alternative ways to creating a `Background` object.</sup>